# How can i forward mediagroup in python telegram bot?

Tags: python, telegram, py-telegram-bot-api

I want to create a telegram bot in which a user can send a media group along with text and another user will receive it as a media group. I know that it can be done with sendmediagroup, but how to do it so that the media does not need to be saved, but can be forwarded immediately, like copy_message or forward_message?

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `sendMediaGroup()` to send media files instead of forwarding it. Forwarding media group files is not supported yet I think.